# Delta method, or something in addition to understand this problem.

Tags: statistics

I am self studying and the following is a problem that I have very little idea of how to solve.

Suppose X1, X2, . . . are iid Bernoulli(p) random variables. For large n, what is the approximate distribution of $\ln{\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)}$, the log-odds in favour of $X_1=1$ versus $X_1=0$?

So far the only thing I know is that

$$\sqrt{n}(f(\bar{X}-f(\mu))) \rightarrow N(0,[f'(\mu)]^2\sigma^2)  
 \space \text{as} \space n\rightarrow\infty$$
which is supposedly the delta method.

All I want to know is to have some guidance towards what to study in order to be able to solve this problem.

I appreciate your help and time.

Comment: Do you mean asymptotic distribution of $\ln\left(\frac{\bar X}{1-\bar X}\right)$? $\ln{\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)}$ is not random.

Comment: I just copied and pasted the exact problem so I don't know... that was actually one of the things that I was wondering, but since 1-p is the complement of p I wasn't sure if it really is a typo or not.  Would you be able to answer the question if it was $\bar{X}$ instead of $p$?

Comment: If it was $\bar X$ instead of $p$, use delta-method with $f(x)=\ln(\frac{x}{1-x})$.